# Python and Blender. Why does any editing on my box create a new box?

Tags: python

So im pretty new to this. I'm using python on blender and i created a box with this code

```
import bpy 

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
box = bpy.context.active_object

box.location[2] = 4
box.location[0] = 2
```

The issue is, when i run the code blender creates a brand new cube and moves it

Answer (score 4):

So lets add line-by-line comments to your code:

```
# Import bpy tells Python you're using the Blender main library
import bpy 

# create a brand new cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

# make 'box' a reference to the active object
box = bpy.context.active_object

# set the box's z location to 4
box.location[2] = 4
# set the box's x location to 2
box.location[0] = 2
```

As you can perhaps see from the comments, every time you execute bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(), you're going to get a new cube. Removing that line means you will move whatever object is active. You could explicitly move the default cube with:

```
 box = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

Where 'Cube' is the name in the outliner.

You can also move the box using a vector like this:

```
 box.location = (2,0,4)
```